# iOS GPUImage capture an image from GPUImageVideoCamera

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm building a simple app, to get used to GPUImage.

The app show the camera view, with the GPUImageToonFilter on.

I would like to snap a photo, but it's seams like everything I can get is null, but I believe I'm doing it wrong. can you tell me what's wrong in my code ?

// Init :

```
_camera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
_camera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
_GPUview = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
_cartoonFilter = [[GPUImageToonFilter alloc] init];
[_cartoonFilter forceProcessingAtSize:_GPUview.sizeInPixels];
[_cartoonFilter addTarget:_GPUview];
[_camera addTarget:_cartoonFilter];
[_camera startCameraCapture];
[self.view addSubview:_GPUview];
```

then I add an button in the subview that call this methode when clicked inside :

```
- (IBAction)shootAction:(id)sender {
     [_camera pauseCameraCapture];
     [_cartoonFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
     self.imageView.image = [_cartoonFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
    [_GPUview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I've tried to used all the methode, on every Filter/Camera that I've here, and `imageFromCurrentFramebuffer`, `imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation:` always return `(null)`

Thanks guys if you can bring me anyhelp :)

Comment: You pause the camera, then you ask for the next frame to capture?

Comment: @CasWolters: yeah, I didn't write this line at the beginnin' but since all the answer on StackOverflow about capturing an image was about this line, I added it, without really thinking, now that you said it, it's pretty dumb from me ahah. (still didn't fix the problem tho)